# iPad USB Charging Utility for Dell Optiplex

Tags: usb, ipad, dell-optiplex

As you probably know already, an iPad requires a certain power on USB port to be charged from. 
Thus, some motherboard manufacturers (such as ASUS, Gigabyte etc) had released a special driver that recognizes that an iPad is connected to the port and adjust the USB power accordingly.

On one of my computers (Gigabyte motherboard) it works fine. But other one is [Dell Optiplex 780](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/optiplex-780/pd) and the regular googling by `"<motherboard type> + iPad charging"` doesn't seem to bring encouraging results.

Just for completeness: no, the iPad is not being charged without any special driver installed (out of the box) either.

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: How can you *adjust the USB power?*

Comment: @pavium: http://www.gigabyte.com/microsite/185/on-off-charge.htm - just an example.

Comment: This looks like marketing hype. The USB standard requires USB ports provide a *fixed* voltage of 5V. How could a *driver* change either the voltage or the current compliance? If the voltage is fixed (as it must be) the speed of charging is determined by the device being charged.

Comment: The comment above is correct. You MAY need to install iTunes to get the iPodSupport files to recognize it

Comment: I am sorry, this has nothing to do with iTunes and also nothing about file recognition. On my home computer (with Gigabye motherboard), I have no iTunes installed and iPad charging started to work only after I've installed the driver, mentioned above. Not sure how power is measured, I think it's rather about a current: 2amper vs. 0.5amper, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It may be that the USB ports on the Gigabyte motherboard can supply more current than whatever you used previously. It could be just a coincidence that you noticed the faster charging at about the same time as you installed the *driver*.

Comment: I have installed the driver on purpose. A second before it didn't worked and a second after it worked. I have friends with ASUS motherboard that confirmed that proper driver exist for their vendor as well. Though the issue is new to me, it is pretty common in iPad/apple-related community. Also, there are other drivers/applications like AppCharger (http://www.asrock.com/feature/appcharger/index.asp). I am sure that the situation becomes convincing enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a hardware issue,

"GIGABYTE's latest motherboards are equipped with ON/OFF Charge technology"

If it is not incorporated into the motherboard, then no driver can modify the USB chip and circuitry on a standard motherboard. Obviously your Dell does not have this motherboard feature.

Standard USB is 500 milliamps, no way to upgrade this to 2 amps with a driver, you need a special USB chip/circuit on the motherboard to do this.

Comment: I know it is a hardware issue. I was trying to understand IF my Dell Optiplex 780 motherboard supports such a functionality. I just can't get which motherboard is it. You say that it is obvious that my dell does not have it. Assumed it comes from your common knowledge. Just re-assuring/re-validating.

Comment: If Dell supported this feature, they would advertise it like crazy, yes obvious to me, maybe not you. I doubt they ever will since Apple is a direct competitor.

Answer (score 0):

My Dell XPS 8300 is in no way anounced to be able to charge iPad by USB when using it at the same time, and it doesn't with default drivers.

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) tells me the motherboard is

- Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
- Model: 0Y2MRG A00
- Chipset: Intel, Sandy Bridge, Rev. 09
- Southbridge: Intel, H67, Rev. B3
- LPCIO: ITE, IT8772

BIOS

- Brand: Dell Inc.
- Version: A06 (updated by Dell driver download)
- Date: 10/07/2011

...but, installing Asus AI Charger, I'm completely able to charge it at the same time that I use it. Give it a try, download it from:

- http://event.asus.com/mb/2010/ai_charger/

I've also tried first to install Gigabyte On/Off driver, it gives no error, but doesn't have any effect, so i uninstalled it.